# Programatically create paragraphs entity form

Tags: entities, paragraphs

I am in a situation where I would like to split out Paragraph entities to separate forms.

Edit forms are no problem:

```
$entity = Paragraph::load($entity_id);
return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

But how do I get the create form?
So far I have this:

```
$entity = Paragraph::create();
return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

... but the information about the node and field to attach the paragraph entity to is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only information you need to get the create form of a content entity is the bundle (if the entity has bundles):

```
$entity = Paragraph::create(['type' => 'my_paragraph_type']);
return \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
```

You can do the rest after submitting, but you need to update both, the information of the parent entity in the paragraph and vice versa. Paragraphs references are bi-directional.

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!